# How to create a small form that pull data out of a database in Drupal

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-modules

I created a content type for some Quizz on my site, and now I'd like to create a basic form (only available to admins) to pull some stats on them.

The fields used for the quizz are name, start date, end date and correct answer. Each of these fields should be a searchable criteria in the form, and return a list of quizz. There should also be a relationship with the user table to display a list of those who answered the quizz.

Later I'm gonna need an option to extract the data in excel, but let's focus on the form first.

The version i'm using is Drupal6 and please take in consideration that I'm still pretty new to Drupal.

How can I do this?

Comment: This video tutorial might be helpful: http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you are using CCK for the 'quiz' content type?

If you are, then the best way to 'mash' this data up with getting overly complex is to use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views). You can think of views as an interactive SQL query builder.

You can create pages, blocks or even RSS feeds from the output of Views.

Comment: Cool, that really helps me figure out how I will do it. However, I'd need the view to be dynamic; for example, the user could "filter" the data based on the quiz published date. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you would want to use an exposed filter in Views.

Answer (score 0):

Module [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) seems like a valid alternative to consider. For more details about Forena, 2 types of documentation are available:

- [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363).
- Documentation that comes with Forena, which you can access right after install and enable of the module. Checkout the [demo site](http://www.forenasolutions.org) for an online example of the current:

  - **Forena documentation** - use the link 'Reporting documentation' or visit relative link /reports/help.
  - **Forena samples** - use the link 'Reporting samples' or visit relative link /reports/samples (these samples are fully functional, so make sure to experiment a bit with it, such as the drill downs available on the SVG Graph sample).

The newest 7.x-4.x version also includes an amazing (I think) UI for either creating your reports (the WYSIWYG report editor) and/or for creating your SQL queries (the Query Builder).

**Be aware**: I'm a co-maintainer of Forena.